# Exporting image from asp.net to excel via HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, vb.net, excel

I've been trying to export a chart with other data to an excel file. I would prefer to export it as an excel formatted HTML file since the existing reports are already generated that way.

I've tried simply linking the image but that relies on the image being online for it to display in excel. I've also tried to export the image as an embedded data URI but excel doesn't parse it (file displays fine in a browser). I'm thinking zipping the worksheet with the image ought to work but that would make things complicated and require the user to go through an extra step when opening the report.

Is there a better way or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

Dude use vba macros tools giving provided in the microsoft office excel for code development and exporting or importing all kinds off stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(Response.OutputStream);

zip.AddStringAsFile(FileIO.OptimizeHtml(htmlWrite.InnerWriter.ToString()), filename.xls", "");

zip.Save();